How to calibrate a compass module that isn't producing elliptical data?
My company is working on something similar to (but not the same as, but it's just easier to explain it like this) an electronic prize wheel, mounted horizontally.
The method of detecting which prize is under the pointer is to use a 2-axis compass unit, specifically the V2Xe (archived).
In my case, the wheel looks like this and has the compass module mounted near the edge of the wheel, so it spins around the circumference of the wheel whenever the wheel is spun.

I've been reading about how to calibrate compasses and magnetometers, and it looks like you should fit an ellipsoid (or, in the 2-axis case I have here, an ellipse) to the raw data. The data then needs to be transformed to a sphere (circle). To my understanding, the translation part of that transform is for the hard-iron correction, and the rest is the soft-iron correction. This transform can be used to convert any new raw data point into the coordinate space of a unit circle.
Sounds easy, right? I've pulled some raw data from several rotations of one of the modules and loaded it into Python to generate some graphs and use skimage's ellipse fit function. The raw data, when plotted, looks like so:

I am able to perform the ellipse fit using the following code:
ellipse = skimage.measure.EllipseModel()
ellipse.estimate(data)
params = ellipse.params
transform = scale_matrix(1/params[2], 1/params[3]) @ rotation_matrix(-params[4]) @ translation_matrix(-params[0],-params[1])
data = np.vstack((data, np.ones(len(data[0]))))  # convert (x,y) to (x,y,1)
data = transform @ data

I have functions scale_matrix, rotation_matrix, and translation_matrix which just generate the 3x3 matrix that it says it will. ellipse.params contains the following data: (center_x, center_y, scale_x, scale_y, rotation).
Although the calculated ellipse should fit, it doesn't (at least not perfectly). If I plot the data (not pictured), the calculated ellipse is close-ish, but definitely not a perfect fit by any means.
When this transformed data is plotted, I should get a circle. I don't. Instead, I get this:

Yes, it looks circle-ish, but this is nowhere near accurate enough. The final step in my calibration is to convert the x,y data into an angle and then, knowing the position of one of the prizes, I can evenly space out the remaining prize positions by dividing the circle by the number of prize segments.
If I manually calibrate the wheel (rotate to each prize position and record the compass x,y data), I can also find the corresponding angle for each segment. When I compare the data, there are some major differences, with up to an error of ~0.5 segments. I know the manual calibration is good because it works when the wheel is spun. The ellipse calibration doesn't.

(This is also the best fit I can get between the two different calibration datapoints. I looped through thousands of starting angles to find the one with the lowest MSE between points.)
EDIT: I realised I didn't explain what this picture was. The calculated positions are spaced at equal angles (360/N, where N is the number of segments) around the "circle" produced by transforming the ellipse data back to a circle. The X,Y coordinates on the circle are then transformed back to the ellipse coordinates using the inverse transform matrix. I just as easily could've shown this data on the circle, and you would see that the "calculated positions" would be spaced at equal angles around it (although the arc length between them would vary due to the shape not actually being a circle)
My theory is that the calibration is failing because the raw data is not an ellipse. It is more of an egg shape. I see some other weird shapes on some of the units too, so it's not just this one. And then there are other units which produce raw data that is already very circular, so those are simple to calibrate.
I'm aware that this compass module does contain an internal method for calibration, but for legacy reasons, this would require a lot of work to implement this without breaking other stuff. So, I'd prefer to calibrate it based on the raw data instead as that requires minimal changes to the existing code that interfaces with the compass module.
Anyway, my question is, how do I handle this egg-shaped data? Maybe this is more of a question for math.stackexchange, but I figure someone here will have had a similar experience.

Remember, the prize wheel is just an easier way to explain what it is and also contains none of my company's IP. If you have any questions about why something has been done a particular way, my answer will probably be "it was like this when I got here".

You appear (to me) to have unapplied a-priori knowledge to form more optimal filtering. Given this may be key to some corporate IP, that's all I'll add.

Current in nearby wires can cause distortion. Have you been careful to keep current paths well away from your sensor? Or at least, current path in closely adjacent to current path out (like twisted pair)?

Could you post the measured data (array of points, CSV, JSON, whatever..)? Also, is the pattern repeatable from unit to unit (between sensors, magnets, etc.), or will a measurement and calibration method also be required? || Topicality could be argued, but I for one would argue it's applicable: such matters arise in the design of controls, transfer functions, sensors, calibration, etc. After that, I'd say the next most likely candidate is probably DSP.SE, and then general engineering, physics, mathematics; all of which include the same basic problem (match series to a curve).

@TimWilliams The pattern is not repeatable between units. Some have an almost circular pattern, some have almost elliptical patterns, and others have warped shapes like the one in my question (which was the worst one I saw, but I haven't seen all of them). Each unit is in a different location (with customers), so there are environmental factors at play. Each unit will need to be calibrated on site, including if anything is placed nearby that might affect the magnetic field.I'll have to trim some of the data to share it because it's a lot of very dense data

Just the measured points (red Xs) would do. I wouldn't think there's much to do with the whole dataset (yellow) without known angles; or at least unless those data are at constant angular velocity or something like that?

@tomnexus I think you might be on to something. I was under the impression that "soft iron distortion" referred to any interference sources that didn't also rotate with the sensor. Is that not the case? —Most locations do have metal near the sensor, and maybe magnetic materials. As you correctly stated, these are installed indoors. —What effect does being off-axis have? I assumed that'd just reduce the magnitude, not warp the data, because the field is on the sensor's z-axis, which the 2D compass doesn't see. —Are you suggesting calibration isn't possible without knowledge of nearby metal?

I believe you have some magnetostatic error causing an "eccentric ellipse" which requires curve-fitting two ellipses (2D) or ellipsoids (3D) on each end of the major axis.
In this case, I used the larger of two ellipses on the short axis and long axis with only the end with the smaller radius. Then the inside or smaller of two ellipses on the long axis on the end with the larger radius to get a closer match combining two elliptical paths into one.

To create it I did the following;

rotate the long axis to 0 deg.
draw a rectangle around the mean egg shape.
Create an ellipse from any rectangle left and right corner that best fits each half of the egg.

That made it easier to avoid hunting for the x,y center and length r of each radius.

Your problem is most likely that you are moving the sensor through space, with magnetic objects nearby.
The LSM303DLH datasheet has a good explanation of the principles of calibrating a magnetometer to measure its orientation in earth's magnetic field.
From the end of the calibration chapter (my emphasis):

Please note that the magnetic sensor calibration can only compensate the hard-iron and soft-iron interference magnetic field generated by the handheld device itself. This means that during full round rotations of the calibration, the hard-iron and soft-iron fields also rotate with the device.
The electronic compass is sensitive to environmental magnetic interference fields outside of the handheld device. A single Z-axis gyro chip can be used to aid the compass when environmental magnetic interference is detected.

So a compass can only be calibrated by a simple method, if the hard and soft iron move with it like you would have on a ship or in a smartphone.
If you sweep a field sensor through a space, nearby to other magnetic objects, the field it will see could be much more complex than a simple ellipse.
Imagine for example there was a small magnet near the pointer in your picture. The sensor would see earth's magnetic field for most of the rotation, and then a big bump as it passed the magnet.
To test this, try repeating your calibration with the table in different orientations, see which artefacts move with the "wheel" and which with the "table".
Some ideas for a solution:

Calibrate in detail using another angle measurement method to provide the known angles.

Compensate for later sensor scale and drift over time/temperature by detecting changes to the size and position of the "blob" / "wave" but not attempting to fit an ellipse.

Assuming your device is used outdoors, and the only nearby object is its support structure, you may be able to improve the repeatability of the calibration by always mounting the fixed part in the same orientation as when it was was first calibrated at the factory. Difficult if you're shipping them far from where they were made, when the magnetic dip changes...

You may get some benefit from integrating the output of a MEMS rate gyro and fusing it with the wobbly compass data. This will work best if it moves fairly quickly, say 5 seconds per revolution or faster. The gyro-determined angle will be quite accurate over a few seconds, while the compass will be more accurate for initial absolute positioning, and when moving very slowly.



For all of the above experiments, I strongly recommend starting with just your phone and an app like "physics toolbox" which can plot and log the magnetic, gyro and accelerometer sensor values to a csv file.
Here are two rotations of my phone - the first just turning it carefully in place, well away from other objects:

And the second one holding it in my hand while swiveling my chair, passing over my laptop, keys, phone charger etc. OK maybe I overdid it a bit, but you can see the problem with your setup.

